# Help dual booting on Lenovo Yoga 900-13ISK2

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

this is my first post here.
I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu and the Preinstalled Windows 10 on my Yoga 900-13ISK2. I've been trying to learn from forums how to do this, but I finally hit a dead end.
I did the following steps:
1) Turn on Minimal Safeebot
2) Restart UEFI settings
-This is where I found I did not have the option to change from RAID to AHCI
3) Downloaded the BIOS package that allows the option to switch (from 2016)
But upon trying to install it, it says "the version of ROM file is not newer than that of BIOS"
Does anyone know how to fix this and maybe anticipate any other problems I might hit?